# Dynamically adding an active class to a custom menu in Wordpress with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, dynamic

I have an old website I had to copy over to Wordpress. I created a custom theme to achieve this. I have a custom navbar that I am pulling in a custom sidebar.php file. I am also hooking in the pages by page ID as you can see in my markup. I have not been able to dynamically add an active class to highlight on the navbar which page they are on. I have tried plenty of jQuery but to no avail. I am also linked in boostrap for responsiveness.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div id="leftnav">
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li>
      <!-- Link to section at level 2 -->
      <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(202); ?>">The Battle &amp; Beyond</a>
      <!-- navigation object : Menu - Left Navigation -->
      <ul class="nav-bar">
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(204); ?>">Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(212); ?>">The Ravine</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(215); ?>">Groggin's Field</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(218); ?>">Oldbridge Village</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(220); ?>">Battle Artillery</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(224); ?>">King William's Camp</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(226); ?>">King James's Camp</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(228); ?>">Crossing the Ford</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(233); ?>">The River Crossing</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(235); ?>">King William's Crossing</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(237); ?>">The Retreat</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use menus in wpp backend and called wp_nav_menu()

Comment: Oh ok could I still use the the page ID to call it? For example wp_nav_menu(204)

Comment: No, please read how to add menu in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to do this (but not the recommended "WordPress" way of doing this) is to add an if statement on your `<li>` or `<a>` tags to check for the current page ID like this:

```
<div id="leftnav">
  <ul class="nav-bar">
    <li>
      <!-- Link to section at level 2 -->
      <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(202); ?>">The Battle &amp; Beyond</a>
      <!-- navigation object : Menu - Left Navigation -->
      <ul class="nav-bar">
        <li <?= (is_page(204)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(204); ?>">Map</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(212)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(212); ?>">The Ravine</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(215)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(215); ?>">Groggin's Field</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(218)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(218); ?>">Oldbridge Village</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(220)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(220); ?>">Battle Artillery</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(224)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(224); ?>">King William's Camp</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(226)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(226); ?>">King James's Camp</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(228)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(228); ?>">Crossing the Ford</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(233)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(233); ?>">The River Crossing</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(235)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(235); ?>">King William's Crossing</a></li>
        <li <?= (is_page(237)) ? 'class="active"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(237); ?>">The Retreat</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The "WordPress" way would be to register a new nav menu so that you can dynamically create a menu on the backend. When you do that, you can display the dynamic menu and WordPress will automatically add the active classes for you.

functions.php file

```php
function register_my_custom_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('sidebar-menu', __( 'Sidebar Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_custom_menu' );
```

sidebar.php file:

```php
<div id="leftnav">
    <ul class="nav-bar">
        <li>
            <!-- Link to section at level 2 -->
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(202); ?>">The Battle &amp; Beyond</a>
            <!-- navigation object : Menu - Left Navigation -->
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
                    'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu',
                    'menu_class' => 'nav-bar'
                ) 
            ); ?>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Once you have this in place, login to your WordPress admin and go to Appearance > Menu's and you can build your menu there.

References:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: Brilliant thanks a million for that! It worked with the proper "Wordpress way". I also targeted the current active classes parents and ancestor

Answer (score 0):

With the help of mread1208 above I found the most efficient solution.

The HTML for the sidebar.php (or sidebar-whateveryouwant.php) file.
Note: in the backend of Wordpress when building your menu tick the box 'Sidebar Menu' in Menu Settings below your menu structure.

```
<div id="leftnav">
<ul class="nav-bar">
    <li>
        <!-- Link to section at level 2 -->
        <a href="<?php echo get_page_link(202); ?>">The Battle &amp; Beyond</a>
        <!-- navigation object : Menu - Left Navigation -->
        <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'sidebar-menu',
                'menu_class' => 'nav-bar'
            )
        ); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Added to the functions.php file:

```
   // Adds custom menu
function register_my_custom_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('sidebar-menu', __( 'Sidebar Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_custom_menu' );
```

In your CSS target the active classes:

```
#leftnav ul li.current_page_item > a, #leftnav ul li.current_page_parent > a, #leftnav ul li.current-menu-ancestor > a, #leftnav ul li.current-menu-item > a, #leftnav ul li.current-menu-parent > a {
background-color: #ffc107;
border-color: 4em solid #ffc107;}
```

Hope that helps someone.